# Cannot Successfully Install Vim with Ruby Support in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vim

I am using Ubuntu. Right now, the command `:echo has('ruby')` in my vim session will show 0. So I tried to fix the problem by the following commands,

`sudo apt-get install ruby rubygems vim-nox`

and run the command `:echo has('ruby')` again after restarting the operating system. However, it still shows 0.
It seems that Rubby Support was not successfully installed in Ubuntu. What might be the problem and how can I fix this?

[output of `:version' command in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1qzw.png)

Comment: What is ruby support? Are you trying to install ruby in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the version of Vim you're using has Ruby support by running `vim --version`. That should print out a list of options, hopefully including `+ruby`. It should also print a set of features, right before that list. If you're using `vim-nox`, then you should see "Huge version" (either "with GUI" or "without GUI").

If you are missing either one of those, then you're probably configured to use the wrong Vim version. In Debian and Ubuntu, Vim is controlled by the alternatives system. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config vim`, which will provide you a list of Vims that are on your system. Ensure you pick the either `/usr/bin/vim.nox` or `/usr/bin/vim.gtk3`, since these versions have Ruby support. You can also pick automatic mode, since that should pick one of those versions if they're installed.

Comment: First, the output of `vim --version` shows `-ruby`. Second, the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config vim` shows that                                                                 
Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.nox     40        manual mode
which means the one I picked is auto mode, right?

Comment: Yeah, in this case you'll need to pick `vim.nox`, because apparently `vim-gtk3` doesn't support Ruby in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, update the packages index:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install Ruby by typing:

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

To verify that the installation it was successful run the following command which will print the Ruby version:

```
ruby --version
```

The output will look something like this:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: After running the commands you provided, I got the same output. However, when I run the vim command `:version` in Vim editor, I can see a list of features included by Vim and the sign in front of ruby is `-` rather than `+`. Essentially, I want this to be `+` because the plugin only works under this condition.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by running the command `sudo update-alternatives --config vim` and then type `3` to choose `vim.nox`; in this case, the sign in front of ruby is `+` after running the command `vim --version`.